# What is the difference between "Google+ sign in" and "Federated Log-in" and "Google Users Service"?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I want to add social sign-in feature to my Google App Engine based application and hence want to add Google's authentication mechanism along with FB log-in.

I am confused because Google has provided at least 3 different ways to do this.

1. Google+ sign-in (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)
2. Users service provided on Google App Engine
3. Federated Authentication (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid)

I would like to know which method is the most recent and which method is used widely?

Thanks,

Chandrashekhar

Comment: `1` and `2` use a Google user's credentials, but `1` requires Google+ to be enabled for that user (it is possible to have a Google account without G+). `3` is OpenID, which is independent of a Google account.

Comment: Please provide reason for downvote

Comment: neutralized the downvote as the question is definitely worthwhile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#1 [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in) allows users to log in via OAuth 2.0, but requires users to have Google Plus enabled. Google+ Sign In also provides additional functionality to the Google+ APIs such as sharing and social integration. However, you could just use standard [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) for login, which removes the Google+ requirement.

#2 [Users Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) is a Google App Engine API. It allows any user with a Google Account to login. This is different to OAuth 2.0 - it uses Googles standard login pages and you can use it right out of the box without having to configure any OAuth scopes etc. You can [get going with this very quickly](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers).

#3 [Federated Login](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid) integrates the [Open ID standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) with the Google App Engine Users API. This allows your users to log in with an Open ID (ie credentials they have registered with an 'Open ID provider'), and you to use the standard Users Service API. There are many Open ID providers out there, including Google.

Your question states that you want to add a "social sign-in feature" along with "FB log-in". So, that basically rules #1 & #2 out. Unfortunately, Facebook (and Twitter) are not Open ID providers, so that kind of rules #3 out too. For these, you will need to implement their own authentication mechanisms ([Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.0) and [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter)). There is a great [boilerplate repo on GitHub](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate) that has some code (in python) to help you get going.

Comment: does NOT require users to have Google Plus enabled IF you limit yourself to profile scope. from the docs : "Adding the Google+ Sign-In button with the profile scope provides a simple, secure way to authenticate users with access to only the user's basic information. Users are not prompted to create a Google+ profile." cfr https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration cfr.

Comment: At March 27 2015, there is now ["Google Sign In"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/) which, as far as I can tell, is different from [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/)...? At least there's different web sites.  Maybe this answer could be updated?